# Do I receive bonuses for the building a leader's unique building replaces?

Tags: civilization-5

For example, if I am playing as the Mayan's and I have one city with the following building:

> **Pyramid**:  + 2 Faith + 2 Science *(replaces Shrine)*

and I have founded a pantheon and chosen the following belief:

> **Ancestor Worship**: +1 Culture for every Shrine in your civilization

Does my Pyramid receive the +1 Culture bonus?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yup.

The buildings are fundamentally equivalent in the game, which is why you need to build a Pyramid in every city (instead of a monument) if you're seeking to build the National Epic, and the same thing follows if you're building Steles instead.